# Reduction of species variables in vegetative analysis

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, exploratory-data-analysis, ecology

Edited following helpful feedback.

I have vegetation species data for a number of grassland habitat sites, and am preparing to begin Exploratory Data Analysis.
Data was collected in 100 quadrats over 9 sites in percent cover to attempt to establish one or more species which indicate improved quality of grasslands over time through their presence or abundance (%).

```
Quadrat   Site   Soil.type  Mean.quadrat.height.cm  Species.1%  Species.2% Species.3%...
1          2       3               40                  5           10         25
2          3       2               50                  0           0          10
3          2       1               25                  10          0          0
```

I am confident in the steps I need to take to ensure rigorous data analysis, and I'm not attempting to shirk any long winded jobs, but I wanted to see if I should be reducing the number of species variables before going further.  I have over 100 separate species, some of which only occur on one occasion.  Certain papers I have seen recommend removing any species which only occur in <5% of quadrats, but I don't know how to back this up.  To be on the safe side should I conduct EDA (boxplots etc.) on every single variable, or is there a robust method of species reduction? I had originally thought PCA should do the trick but some literature I have read says other forms of EDA should come before PCA.

Thanks

Comment: Not everybody here is familiar with vegetation research. Please formulate your question such that it is clear for as many people as possible. What exactly is your data? You have over 100 species. You "measure" them in different places? Are there "quadrats"? What are these measurements? How many places are there? For complete clarity, can you maybe show a small part of your data table? And finally: what is the purpose of the analysis?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but what are "indicator species of succession"?

Comment: I am sorry, I still don't get it. Do you have an independent measure of the "quality of grasslands"? In that case you probably want to correlate your species abundance with it? Or if you don't have an independent measure of quality, then how would you know which species indicate it?

Comment: EDA has nothing to do with dimensionality reduction (other than giving you useful information that you should use in subsequent phases). So, after you're done with EDA, proceed with one of _dimensionality reduction_ approaches. If you don't care about _latent structure_ of your model, then _PCA_ should do the trick, otherwise you need to perform _factor analysis_ (at least, EFA, but, potentially CFA as well).

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: This is an aside, but I find the strong distinction you are making between PCA and FA ("if you **don't care** about latent structure") not really warranted. See my answer to the question "Is there any good reason to use PCA instead of EFA?" (search for it and it pops up immediately; I intentionally don't give a link, as the questions are not very connected, whereas giving a link makes them officially "related").

Comment: @amoeba: Thanks for pointing to that question. I've seen it earlier and now again. Currently, I don't have enough level of expertise to argue with you or other people on the subject. So, I neither agree, not disagree for now. I still have an opinion, though, which may be unwarranted, as you said. I will definitely study in detail your answer (which is great, BTW - I upvoted it back then) and the others'. Just one simple point, before going into details: if these methods would be approximately equal, why they would be referred to by, using totally different terms? Just a thought. More later...

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: It is a complicated issue with many people having strong (and often opposite) opinions about. So take my word as just one opinion. I did not mean that PCA and FA are approximately equal; they can produce quite different outcomes (but it is very unlikely with 100+ species, as in the OP here). But I insist that they are not so different *conceptually* as many people often think.

Comment: @amoeba: Fair enough! Points well taken. I look forward to learning more from studying a variety of other people's opinions.

Comment: Thank you both for your interesting discussion.  I believe from your discussion that it sounds like further research would be beneficial here, and so if time allows I will use both FA and PCA on the same data and compare the results.  I think I will cover all bases and perform EDA on all variables without further strict guidance.  Many thanks.